# What is the mechanism of the `ghs.google.com` domain?

Tags: google-app-engine

If I want to bind a domain name to my app on the **GAE** (Google App Engine), I should add a CNAME record to **`ghs.google.com`**.  I'd like to understand how this domain works.

For example, I have a CNAME like this: `blog.goace.com`  →  `ghs.google.com`, and my app's URL is ace.appspot.com. When I type http://blog.goace.com  in my browser, what will happen before I see my Gapp on the screen?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your browser sends a request to Google's server with the `Host: yoursite.com` header.

Google looks up this hostname in a (very large) database mapping hostnames to websites, then serves the corresponding website.

This database includes App Engine apps, Google Apps aliases, BlogSpot blogs, and other things.