# Is there a way of checking if a Web Application or Website using the Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to figure out whether to use Google App Engine or other available PaaS. During my research, I am trying to figure out if a particular website using google app engine or not - Is there any known method to figure this out ?

Sorry for the basic question, but appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can recognize a GAE-based site based on the server's domain:

- `*.appspot.com` - default domain of standard GAE apps
- `*.appspot-preview.com` - default domain of newer flex GAE apps
- custom domains mapped to `ghs.google.com` or `ghs.googlehosted.com`. See step 5 in the [Adding a custom domain for your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application) procedure and [how does ghs.google.com work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984719/how-does-ghs-google-com-work). Note that I'm unsure if this doesn't also apply to other Google products, not only to GAE.

There may be other such domains as well.

You can also check the `Server` header in the responses coming from the site. From [Headers added or replaced](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-handled#headers_added_or_replaced):

> **Server**
>
> Set to `Google Frontend`. The development server sets this to
>   `Development/x`, where x is the version number.

Answer (score 0):

ping the domain and if you have something with `ghs.googlehosted.com`:

> `PING ghs.googlehosted.com (216.58.213.147): 56 data bytes`

It's a GAE application. You can also check the headers in requests from your browser's dev tools.